# How to load a .dmp into PostgreSQL using pgadminIII

Tags: python, oracle, postgresql

I have a dump file from oracle that I wish to load into pgSQL database.
I can use psycopg2 or pgAdminIII to accomplish this. Any tutorials or references would be much appreciated as I cant seem to find anything. New to databases here.
Thanks